# How to return a nil CGFloat?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to return `nil` to `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` but that's not allowed.  Is there a way to return `nil` as a CGFloat?

**Why are you doing this?**
I'm testing how a tableView will behave with a mix of Titles and Views as sectionFooters. For one footer I need to use a custom view, but for another footer I have 3 or 4 sentences of text and I like how the system styles it and sizes the footer to fit.  But as soon as I implement `heightForFooterInSection` (which is required by `viewForFooterInSection`), the footer with the title no longer auto-resizes to fit the given text. I'm trying to avoid building a custom view for the straight text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as `nil` for primitive values. You could try returning `0.0f`, but I don't know how UITableView responds to that. It may just hide the view entirely. Presumably if you want to return a custom view for one footer, you need to return a custom view for all footers.

Comment: It looks like you're right. `0.0f` has the same result as returning `0` which in this case causes the system to choose the minimum 'attractive' footer height. So what we've discovered is you can mix and match Title and Views for footers (and headers) but you have to manually set the heights for all of them. So the easy way is to find the height that shows all the given text, and return that.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, there is no such thing as a `nil` for floats.

However, the Department of Ugly Hacks brings you: The NaN - "NaN" being a special reserved value of the float bit pattern representing "Not a Number".

No clue what a UITableView will make of a NaN, but in other situations it can be a way to specify that a `float` variable does not have a value.

If you won't tell anyone where you got the idea, here is the code:

```
CGFloat myNan = nanf(NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for that bit of 'nan-wisdown'. It helped me determine that it doesn't matter what you return from `heightForFooterInSection`, the system will assume you want control and it won't calculate it's own height.

Comment: `NaN` is a rather special value (along with `Inf` and `-Inf`, and also `-0` but most code doesn't distinguish between `-0` and `0`). I would not be surprised if UIView or CoreAnimation code blows up when it encounters a `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: 'nil' is a pointer to nothing, used in place of a pointer to an object. CGFloat is a scalar datatype, not an Objective-C class, and is not generally used with pointers (or it would be CGFloat *).

Answer (score 1):

I am late for the party but this may be useful to someone.

Like others said, you cannot return nil to primitives but you can do one of two things, to differentiate a non-set value from a set one.

1. Use `NSNotFound`

   ```
   - (CGFloat)calculateHeight {
      // calculate height...

      if (heightInvalid) return NSNotFound;
      else return validFloatValue;

   }
   ```

NSNotFound is a huge number defined by Apple and used by them on some operations. Then you can check for that, like:

```
if ([self calculateHeight] == NSNotFound) ...
```

2. Use `NSNumber`

Instead of returning a `CGFloat` make your function return a `NSNumber`.

```
      - (NSNumber *)calculateHeight {
         // calculate height...

         if (heightInvalid) return nil;
         else return @(validFloatValue);

      }
```

Then, you can return nil.

When receiving the value you do:

```
NSNumber *myHeightNumber = [self calculateHeight];
if (!myHeightNumber) NSLog(@"height is invalid... do something");
else myHeight = [myHeightNumber floatValue];
```

I hope that helps.